# jquery how to take td value by classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get the value of t here but I can't
how can I do that
if I can take the value I can remove the `<tr>`

exactly what I want to do is get the td value and delete that item from database but I am not getting the value

```
$("body").delegate(".candidateItem .btn-delete", "click", function() {
    if (confirm('Silmek istediğinize emin misiniz')) {
        // here i try the take value

        const resultId = $(this).closest(".CandidateItem").find(".candidateId").val();
        const result = $("#CandidateList").find(".candidateId").val();
        const resulttt = $(".candidateItem").val();
        console.log(resultId);
        $(this).closest(".CandidateItem").remove();
        deleteItem(resultId, "/Candidate/Delete");
        // deleteItem(resultId, "/Project/DeleteProjectCandidate");
        alert('Aday silindi');
        // if ($("#AssessorList .assessorItem").length == 0) {
        //     var assessorList = document.getElementById("AssessorList");
        //     assessorList.style.visibility = "hidden";
        // }
    } else {}
});
```

Here I add the 1 tr when press the saveCandidateButton

```
  $("#CandidateList").append(`<tr class="candidateItem" id="${res.candidateId}">\
                                <td class="candidateId" style="display:none">${res.candidateId}</td>\
                                <td >${res.candidateName}</td>\
                                <td>${res.candidateLastname}</td>\
                                <td>${res.candidatePhone}</td>\
                                <td>${res.candidateMail}</td>\
                                <td>${res.simulationDate}</td>\
                                <td>${res.simulationTime}</td>\
                                <td id="${res.assessorId}">${selValue}</td>\
                                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete"\
                                type="button"><span\
                                    class=" fas fa-minus-circle"></span></button></td>\
                                </tr>\
                                `);
```

Comment: `td` elements do not have `value` attributes and therefore `val()` will retrieve nothing. Use `text()`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I already try this but doesn't worked like this
const resultId = $(".CandidateId").textContent;
        const resultIddd = $(".CandidateId").innerHTML;
        const result = document.getElementsByClassName("CandidateId").textContent;

Comment: There are 3 different usages here.

Comment: None of those match what I wrote in my comment though. Just replace `val()`, where you're using that to get the value of a `td`, with `text()`. Not `textContent`. Not `innerHTML`. And don't change the jQuery that comes before.

Comment: this is worked thank you so much <3

Comment: yes it answers my question

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by adding an attribute such as data-id in the tr tag. I am sharing an example below.

```js
$('.dlt_btn').on('click' , function(){
  var targetId = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
  
  alert(targetId)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="1">
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td><button class="dlt_btn">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="2">
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td><button class="dlt_btn">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="3">
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td><button class="dlt_btn">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="4">
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td><button class="dlt_btn">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="5">
    <td>Item 5</td>
    <td><button class="dlt_btn">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't use it because the id changes dynamically on each of them when adding it to the database so the first time I add it the id becomes 1. and as you add data the id's in tr will constantly change

Comment: As far as I can see you are using the id of that data to delete a data. Also, when you add a new data, I think the id value of that data is returned to you. If you add the id value to the data-id attribute value of each data as below, your problem will be solved.

 `$("#CandidateList").append("<tr data-id='${res.candidateId}'></tr>")`

Comment: Yes you got it right, I hadn't thought of that. thank you but i already solved my problem in a simpler way